# Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v/Ctrl+p not working on vim

Tags: linux, vim, vi, bindings

I'm trying to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> work on vim, but it doesn't work as properly.
I'm using Linux (Debian)

My config files (.vimrc):

```
...
map <C-p> "+P
vnoremap <C-c> "+y
inoremap <C-v> <Esc> "+p 
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The maps seem to work for me, after I remove the extraneous space from your last line. What are you seeing happen when you try to use them?

Comment: What do you want or expect them to do?

Comment: I expect to copy and paste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is simply use a vim version with access to clipboard.

To see if your vim version has access to clipboard, run:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

If you see `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard`, you are good to go. If it's `-clipboard` and `-xterm_clipboard`, you will need to look for a version of Vim that was compiled with clipboard support. On Debian and Ubuntu, to obtain clipboard support install the packages `vim-gtk` or `vim-gnome`  (not `vim-tiny`).

Font: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard

Comment: So it's not "Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v/Ctrl+p" that don't work, it's `"+`.

Comment: Yes,I think so.

Comment: @victorlocateli if I see `-xterm_clipboard` how can I fix it sir? Thanks in advance!